# pubnub publish sync response

Tags: python, pubnub

What is the response from the pubnub synchronous publish method in python?

Based on trial and error, it seems to be an `envelope` instance which has a `envelope.status.category` attribute. It seems that when it succeeds, the status is `PNStatusCategory.PNAcknowledgementCategory` (or if you try to print it without looking up what it is in the source code, `2`). If it fails (for example, by disconnecting internet or giving a bad key), I get a PubNubException.

Are there other possibilities? Does `envelope.status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNAcknowledgmentCategory` mean that the post succeeded? Is there some general documentation for this call somewhere that I couldn't find?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory


def callback(envelope, status):
    print 'Error!'
    print envelope
    print status

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = <your subscribe key>
pnconfig.publish_key = <your publish key>
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

envelope = pubnub.publish().channel('data').message('test').sync()
print envelope.status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNAcknowledgmentCategory
```

Comment: See https://github.com/pubnub/python/blob/6edc4326ffe652e5f4f3db4e10aaaa6e0ea028e1/pubnub/enums.py#L13 for details of all the possible status types.

Comment: @CraigConover Those names are a bit opaque. Just from looking at the list I can only guess which ones might be possible. There isn't any more documentation about what these mean?